# Cannot set property, CLLocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I am trying to set a CLLocation property (named objectLocation) of a custom class, using the below code, called from my main ViewController. Unfortunately, I receive an error telling me on the "commented" line, that the "expression is not assignable." locationsArray is an array of objects of the custom class. I really need to set this value, so any help is appreciated!

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
for (int i = 0; i < [locationsArray count]; i++) {

if ([locationsArray[i] objectLocation] == NULL) {
    [locationsArray[i] objectLocation] = [locations lastObject]; //retrieves most recent location data - THIS IS THE LINE THAT RECEIVES THE ERROR
    //now set up a region and start monitoring data for that region
    [locationsArray[i] region] = [[CLRegion alloc]
                                          initCircularRegionWithCenter:
                                          [[locationsArray[i] objectLocation] coordinate]
                                                                radius:2
                                                            identifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [locationsArray[i] objectLocationName]]];
       }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a property of `CLLocation` within your class and given that your `locationsArray` holds the object and your `locations` array does hold a `CLLocation` object, then please try the following:

```
((<YOUR_CLASS>*)[locationsArray[i]).objectLocation = [locations lastObject];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The casting works to allow the "assignment." However, the CLLocations are still supposedly null.... do you know how to get around that? I want to set the most recent location as the property value, ONLY if that value has not yet been set.

Comment: @Jason Which `CLLocation`? The one in your locationsArray or the ones in locations? Which is supposedly null? It sounds like perhaps you could show more code?

Comment: The locationsArray simply holds instances of a custom class. the objectLocation is a CLLocation property of the custom class objects. This is the CLLocation I would like to set. I use persistent data to reload the values of the array every time the app launches, and I NSLog the objectLocation from each object in the array. Unfortunately, it always logs as null. Is there specific code you would like to see? I can't think of any other code that would be particularly helpful.

Comment: I have edited the code. I placed an NSLog at the beginning of the call to didUpdateLocation, so that I can check the values of the locations array. I also initialized my objectLocation in the custom class. Now the NSLog for the locations array is never called, and the objectLocation coordinates are (0, 0).